# Iptables with -m and -p parameter

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall

I have this rule in my iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9191 -j DROP
```

Do I really need "-m tcp"? I already am using "-p tcp", so should I use "-m tcp" to be more secure?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the `-p tcp` option the tcp module is already loaded and therefor it is somewhat redundant and not a must to use the `-m tcp` option and I don't see any reason why using this option would make the rule more secure.

Please see the [iptables man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) for a better understanding and comparison:

> -p, --protocol [!] protocol
>
> **The protocol of the rule or of the packet to check. The specified 
>   protocol 
>   can be one of tcp, udp, icmp, or all,** or it can be a numeric
>   value, representing one of these protocols or a different one. A
>   protocol name from /etc/protocols is also allowed. A "!" argument
>   before the protocol inverts the test. The number zero is equivalent to
>   all. Protocol all will match with all protocols and is taken as
>   default when this option is omitted.

...

> Match Extensions
>
> iptables can use extended packet matching modules. These are loaded in
>   two ways: implicitly, when -p or --protocol is specified, or with the
>   -m or --match options, followed by the matching module name; after 
>   these, various extra command line options become available, depending
>   on the specific module. You can specify multiple extended match
>   modules in one line, and you can use the -h or --help options after
>   the module has been specified to receive help specific to that module.

And for a list of available option with `-p tcp` see here:

http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbCF

As stated above, with the use of `-m` option it is possible to add extension modules and more matching options are then availble. For example the [cpu module](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbAP):

> cpu
>
> [!] --cpu number
>
> Match cpu handling this packet. cpus are numbered from 0 to NR_CPUS-1 Can be used in combination with RPS (Remote Packet Steering)
>   or multiqueue NICs to spread network traffic on different queues.
>
> Example:
>
> `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -m cpu --cpu 0 -j
>   REDIRECT --to-port 8080`
>
> `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -m cpu --cpu 1 -j 
>   REDIRECT --to-port 8081`
>
> Available since Linux 2.6.36.

Full list of [iptables-extensions.](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbAJ)

---

Additional question from OP: *I dont understand what does -m match. What string? -m tcp matches what? It tries to find the word "tcp" where?*

Answer: `-m` is for matching **module name** and not string. By using a particular module you get certain options to match. See the cpu module example above. With the `-m tcp` the module tcp is loaded. The tcp module allows certain options: `--dport, --sport, --tcp-flags, --syn, --tcp-option` to use in iptables rules. But using `-p tcp` already enables tcp module, that's why one can still use those options even without using `-m tcp`. Hope it clears all your confusion.

Comment: thank you so much, but would care to tell me what the -m would match against? For example, a normal TCP connection, -m would match against what string?Could you provide please an example of the string

Comment: You are welcome. As you can see `-m` option is actually used to load `extension modules` that provides extra options. See my updateds answer and the link for example.

Comment: Thanks! :) One final thought: I think that in my case I should keep the "-m" correct? See this:    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9191 -j DROP    I use "--dport" and I think that it's only possible to use --ddport if I use -m correct?

Comment: @Samul, Not really. You can just use it without the `-m tcp` option. `--dport` is part of the tcp module and will work with `-p tcp` only. Please refer to my answer again.

Comment: You are very kind, thank you! But see: I dont understand what does -m match. What string? -m tcp matches what? It tries to find the word "tcp" where?

Comment: @Samul, Well, `-m` is for matching `module name` and not string. By using a particular module you get certain options to match. See the cpu module example in my answer. With `-m tcp` the module tcp is loaded. The tcp module allows certain options: `--dport, --sport, --tcp-flags, --syn, --tcp-option` to use in iptables rules. But using `-p tcp` already enables tcp module that's why one can still use those options even without using `-m tcp`. Hope it clears all your confusion.